# Numbers of factors of (n)(n+1)/2 is product of exponents?

Tags: combinatorics

I was trying to find the number of factors of $n(n+1)/2$, and I read [this](http://code.jasonbhill.com/sage/project-euler-problem-12/) blog article, and it says that the number of factors of it is the product of its prime factor's exponents with one added to it:

$(e_1)(e_2+1)\cdots(e_s+1)(f_1+1)(f_2+1)\cdots(f_t+1)=e_1\prod_{i=2}^s(e_i+1)\prod_{i=1}^t(f_i+1)$

Why is that? I do not understand.
Here is the article

> If $T(n)$ is the n-th triangular number, then we know that
>
> $T(n)=1+2+\cdots+n=\sum_{i=1}^n=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}.$
>
> Let’s assume that we know the prime factorizations of both n and n+1,
>   and we’ll write
>
> $n = p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\cdots p_s^{e^s}\quad\text{and}\quad n+1 =
> > q_1^{f_1}q_2^{f_2}\cdots q_t^{f_t}$
>
> Notice that $n$ and $n+1$ cannot share any prime factors (as they are
>   consecutive numbers), and so we know that all the $p_i$ and $q_i$ are
>   distinct primes. Also, one and only one of $n$ and $n+1$ are divisible by
>   2. The exponents $e_i$ and $f_i are$ therefore the only things we really need to consider in order to determine the number of divisors of $T(n)$.
>   The fact that T(n)=(n(n+1))/2 means that we’ll need to neglect a
>   single power of two in the factorization of $n$ or $n+1$ (remember, only
>   one is even). Let’s assume, without loss of generality, that $n$ is even
>   and that $p_1=2$. Then, some quick combinatorics tell us that the total
>   number of factors of $T(n)$ will be
>
> $(e_1)(e_2+1)\cdots(e_s+1)(f_1+1)(f_2+1)\cdots(f_t+1)=e_1\prod_{i=2}^s(e_i+1)\prod_{i=1}^t(f_i+1)$
>
> Even better, as we’re increasing our triangular numbers looking for
>   the first one to satisfy the property in question, we only need to
>   calculate the factorization of n+1 (as we already know that
>   factorization of n, as it was previously n+1). This should decrease
>   the runtime substantially.

Comment: The divisor function gives the number of divisors for a given number n: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Comment: Are you wondering about the number of (positive) divisors of $p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ being $(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_k+1)$?

Comment: Yes. a is p's exponent, right? Why would the number of divisors be the product of their exponent+1? I would expect it to be the sum of exponents.

Comment: @CuriousGeorge: Say we are making a factor of $3^4 \cdot 7^1\cdot 13^8$.  First we decide how many $3$'s the factor will have, The factor can have  $0$ $3$'s, or $1$ $3$, or $2$, or $3$, or $4$, a total of $5$ choices. For every such choice, there are $2$ ways to decide how   many $7$'s the factor will have, and then $9$ ways to decide how many $13$'s, for a total of $(5)(2)(9)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example will clear this up.

Look at 
$$
2^3 \cdot 3^4
$$
The divisors of this are of the form $2^i 3^j$, where $i \le 3$ and $j \le 4$, i.e., 
$$
2^0 \cdot 3^0 \\
2^1 \cdot 3^0 \\
2^2 \cdot 3^0 \\
...\\
2^0 \cdot 3^4 \\
2^1 \cdot 3^4 \\
2^2 \cdot 3^4.
$$
Since there are 3 possible powers on the left and 5 on the right, there are a total of 15 possible factors.

In general, a factor of $p^k$ (where $p$ is prime) must be $p^0, p^1, \ldots, p^k$, so there are $k+1$ possibilities.